# Stack Exchange Careers, new resume upload not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Just observed.. New resume uploading in [http://careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is not working.
When we click on "add new resume" before submitting a job application to an employer, yes it shows the file name of the resume that's been uploaded. But if you click
on the filename to make sure before submitting it to the employer, it will show the same
old Resume Contents.
Please fix it asap, I am sure so many candidates have sent their old resume because of this issue without checking...

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed. Thank you for the report !

Note: No worries about the sent resumes! The bug was limited to the candidate side, and the recruiters have received the updated resumes.

Comment: Am still experiencing the same problem. It is annoying not to have the confidence that I sent the right resume. And I can't download my resume from the job preferences section - it just doesn't work. All I can do is checkout a job application I just made and when I checkout the resume attached, it is the old one before I uploaded a new one.